# Support of i18 in vespa

Tags: vespa

Is there support of i18 in vespa so that I can use different languages or vespa can provide me data in different languages? Where can I write properties file for different languages in vespa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linguistic support in Vespa can be found in the documentation; [Linguistics in Vespa](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/linguistics.html). This is what we would normally refer to as internationalization (I18N).

Given your question, though, I wonder if you are looking for localization (L10N) - having the same document exist in multiple languages. This is something you could model having one document per language variant, tag them with the appropriate language and then filter for this in your query.

Comment: For same user, Do I have to create multiple documents for different languages?

Comment: Assume you have, for instance, a document that exist in both English and German. I would index that as two documents and add a field for the "parent/shared" document ID and a field for language. When you query, you need to know the language anyway, so you just filter for one language or the other.

Comment: Suppose I have field _status_ in document whose value is 0 and I want to update it to 1.Then I have to update status in all documents of particular user in all languages. Is this right approach?

Comment: Yes, you would have to update all the relevant documents, unless you use [parent/child relationships](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/search-definitions.html#document-references), but this is only recommended for small number of documents and not something I would recommend.

Alternatively, if you don't need to _search_ in different languages and only want to present the results (from a non-textual search) in different language, you could store the variants in the same document summary (e.g. in an array of strings).

Comment: ok Thanks Frode for help.Please upvote this question if you think it is useful.

Comment: @MohammadSunny: Please resolve question if you got the answer you needed.